# get list name unpacked files without dir

Tags: python, zip, unpack

I'd like to get a list from an unpacked zip file.
I try like this, but it gives me list with dir. list[1:] not work, becouse when is just one file in zip it is extract without folder

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
with ZipFile("test.zip", "r") as f:
    f.extractall(".")
    names = [file.filename for file in f.filelist]
print(names)
```

Output is:

```
['New folder/', 'New folder/asdasd.txt', 'New folder/asdasdsad.txt']
```

I would like it looks:

```
['New folder/asdasd.txt', 'New folder/asdasdsad.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should do:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
with ZipFile("test.zip", "r") as f:
    f.extractall(".")
    names = [file.filename for file in f.filelist if not file.is_dir()]
print(names)
```

We just check if the file is a dir, and if not then it's used.